# How to force reload vimrc file

Tags: vim

It seems that the only thing I can do to (consistently) reload the `vimrc` file is to exit out of it and then re-open it. I have tried doing:

- `:w!` (write)
- `:so $MYVIMRC`

And it doesn't actually update the file. Here is an example video showing how the changes don't apply after updating the vimrc: https://gyazo.com/1a0670c433b6980b5217e15293690845. Is there a better way to force-reload this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.vimrc` is not some sort of a "magical" file. If you source it... well, it's just sourced one more time. All previously defined variables, mappings, commands, etc. will be still here, unless they are overridden inside `.vimrc` itself. You must take this into account.

To unmap an existing mapping you must execute `:unmap` explicitly.

Comment: does that mean that any mappings are not 'unset' when I reload the vimrc? Is there a way to basically 'start from scratch' and reload the vim file? Or for that do I need to literally close it and re-open it?

Comment: would the following command reset everything? `:mapclear | mapclear <buffer> | mapclear! | mapclear! <buffer> | w! | source $MYVIMRC` ?

Comment: @David542 Nothing is unset. Neither mappings, nor abbrevaitions, nor commands... Nothing. No, it won't (isn't guaranteed to) work. There are too many whys and hows it fails. The most obvious things are that `mapclear<buffer>` must be executed in **every** buffer, and all the plugins must be reloaded correctly (impossible in general case), and then filetypes in all buffers are reset... Just forget it.

Comment: I see. So then is there a failproof way to reload a single file? (for example, even reloading the vimrc). Or is the only way to close the file and re-open it again?

Comment: @David542 Just write your vimrc in such a way, so it's mostly safe to re-source it. Not the other way round. When need to unmap and such, do it manually or reload Vim.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `vnoremap`.
The second time around it won't get mapped because you asked vim to disallow it.
Change for `vmap` for the time you are playing around and fine tuning (reloading your vimrc). Once you are happy with it change it back to `vnoremap`

The reason you use `vnoremap` is to avoid having some (rude?) plugin overriding your mappings. Personally I find it (normally) unnecessary. If I ever get to a situation that some plugin overrides my mapping I prefer to figure out who's guilty and get rid of the plugin.